# Discord bot sends replay when a specific user sends a message

Tags: discord.js

```
userID = "7645876345"

client.on("message", function(message) {
    if (message.author.id === userID) {
        message.react('test');
    }
});
```

I'm trying to get the discord bot to reply to a SPECIFIC user every time he writes something.
I changed the userID to random numbers for this post.

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out! I replaced message.react with message.channel.send()

Comment: Please look at the DJS Documentation/Guide, this post wont be any useful.